# Want to send only one email for all the services

Tags: linux, email, notifications, debian, nagios

want to aggregate this to one mail (something like gather all mails for one minute and then send an summary). Is this possible with nagios?.

Comment: Directly in nagios, no. However, you can modify Nagios' notification commands (for example, "notify-service-by-email" found in commands.cfg) so that instead of piping all of the notification information into the unix "mail" command, you could redirect it to a log file.  Then you can use a combination of "logwatch" and cron to mail yourself a digest of the log file at whatever interval you wish.

Comment: Yes @jlyoung I have checked some third party services like nan and nans. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I preferred to disable all email notifications and just use the Web Console for alert checking.